# How to replace catalog component with detailed item component using react router dom?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have a Main component for switching between my main components using routes.

```
const Main = () => {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/" exact component={Landing} />
      <Route
        path="/catalog/:category/:type?/:typeOption?"
        component={Catalog}
      />
      <Route path="???" component={DetailedView} />
      />
    </Switch>
  );
};
```

The Catalog component is basically a list of items available in the store. When a user clicks on one of the items, I want to replace the Catalog component with a component that displays the item with all of its details. When i'm on the detailed page, the url should be the category i was on with the name of the item appended on to it.

For example - I might be on **/catalog/mens/shirts/brown** and when i click on an item, i would be sent to - **/catalog/mens/shirts/brown/nameOfShirt**. I can get the url to send the user to through the match prop, but what do i put for path of my DetailedView component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are looking for [Nested Routing](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start/example-nested-routing)

Inside the main component, the switch would provide only the landing and catalog view.

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/" exact component={Landing} />
  <Route
    path="/catalog/:category/:type?/:typeOption?"
    component={Catalog}
  />
</Switch>
```

Now further inside the catalog view, you can nest the detail with something like:

```
function Catalog({ match }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <Route
        path={match.path + '/:nameOfProduct'}
        component={DetailedView}
      />
      <Route
        exact
        path={match.path}
        render={() => <h3>Render the list of items here</h3>}
      />
    </div>
  )
}
```

This way, the URL is modified to appended to what there earlier.

To handle the optional parameters, you would have to differentiate the ID for `type` and `product` somehow. For eg. If I have a restriction that all product IDs would start with `pr` that would be like:

```
<Switch>
  <Route path={`${match.path}/:id(pr.*)`} render={() => <p>Product</p>} />
  <Route path={match.path} render={() => <p>Still Catalogue</p>} />
</Switch>
```

If you cannot differentiate them using a regex pattern, then you would have to add a routing parameter in the URL, making it:

`/catalog/mens/shirts/product/nameOfShirt`
`/catalog/mens/shirts/type/product/nameOfShirt`

That way you can add the `Route` above the one for `catalog` in the `Switch` statement

Comment: Nested Routing definitely seems like what i'm looking for. But one problem is that my last two parameters in the Catalog route is optional. So it's trying to display a DetailedView whenever there's something after /catalog/:category/. How can I know when it should display a list of items and when it should display a detailed view.